# random thread in cuda confuses array

Tags: cuda

Since the whole code is way to long and messy to be shown here I would just like to know if anybody ever got a similar bug. I show these code snippets:

In CUDA Kernel

```
// ismember is completely NaN at this point and pregpu full of double data
// i is the threadID, these count var just some int to navigate through 1 d array
ismember[i * countxyz] = indiceX;
ismember[i * countxyz + 3 * (countx)] = indiceY;
ismember[i * countxyz + 3 * (countx+county)] = indiceZ;

// Output for debug 
// here I pretty much return the data from pregpu.
 if( i!=20) {
      return;
 }else{ 
    for(int j = 0 ; j < countx; j++) {
        iout[j] = pregpu[i*(countx+county+countz)+j+(i*2)];      
    }          
 }
```

my output looks like that:

```
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA ISMEMBER for like no reason
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
 DATA PREGPU
```

I calculate with around 100 k threads and i get this error 30 times. Every run the errors are in the same threads with the same wrong values. I never call ismember or iout in another part of the code so I'm 100% sure that the call ismember[x] = y sets pregpu[x] = y for like no reason. If I run the thread alone it works so the calculation is right just the multi threading is making troubles.

I would appreciate to know if there is someone who got a similar problem because I'm running out of Ideas what I'm doing wrong. Can there be like a problem with some Kernels so they mess around with data or in case of an out of Bounds from array A the Kernels acces array B.

I initiate the data like:

```
__global__ void trav(double *tout, 
                          double *iout,
                          double *ismember,
                          double *pregpu,
                          double *concatenategpu,
                          [some another unimportant var]
                          )
```

Comment: One word -- [MCVE]. And if you can't provide that, I fail to understand how someone could possibly understand what might be the problem here.

Comment: Im sorry if i couldn't provide the code as its mentioned in the help site but since I'm asking a general question I tried to leave the code short a s possible because it doenst show the problems anyway.

Comment: I am quite new to stack overflow so if you would be a bit more specific what you would like to see in the code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Everything is clearly explained at the link I gave you.  Nobody wants to see all your code. We want to see the minimum amount of code which is complete and illustrates your problem, along with instructions on how to compile and run they code. If you can't do that, CV you're on the wrong place.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i'll try it on the next question.

Answer (score -2):

So i found the mistake by changing the order of the var given to the function.

The array which was given to the function was to short so indexing of out of bounds hits the array given next to the to short one.

I only got Cuda out of bounds if there is no array behind the to short one..